# Javascript Flowtype generic function's callable signature not found

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am trying to declare the type of a function that has the same return type as the parameter type, for a third-party  module.

We can assume the actual function is `a => a`

the `flow-typed` folder contains a file with these declarations:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
  declare var exports: {
    update<T>(param: T): T,
  }
}
```

In my code, I have:

```
import update from 'some-module'
const a: number = update(3)
```

Flow reports this error: function call (Callable signature not found in object type)

Can someone shed some light on the meaning of this error and how I can solve this?

Comment: To me that looks like your exporting an object literal, with a function called update.  So to call it would be more like -> `const a: number = update.update(3)`  I would assume your exports just wants to be `declare var exports: update<T>(param: T): T;`  IOW: Don't stick inside an empty object literal..

Comment: Thank you. The correct declaration was `declare var exports: <T>(param: T) => T`